# Get .NET Link to work on Raspberry Pi

Tags: .netlink, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to get the .NET Link working on Raspberry Pi?

I understand that Linux and MacOS versions of *Mathematica* come with .NET Link running on Mono and now even possibly under new open-source .NET Core:

$\quad \quad$ [Running .NET/Link on Mono (On MacOS or any UNIX or Linux Distro)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20765)

But not RPi:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
```

produces

> ... cannot find the package on RPi.

So to get .NET Link working on RPi, can I use approach similar to copying Python files from desktop version to RPi as described in the following link?

$\quad \quad$ [How to get Python bindings to work on the Raspberry Pi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64817)

Comment: .NET/Link is not included in the Raspberry Pi version of Mathematica.

Comment: The approach used to get Python bindings won't work here.  You can copy the windows version of NETLink to the RPi ("can" doesn't necessarily mean "allowed to"); however, `InstallNET.exe` and the accompanying dll are for Windows, not the RPi, and would need to be recompiled.  There is a 'source' directory included in the NETLink file structure, but I don't know enough about the platform to say whether or not you can recompile for the RPi.  This is probably a good question for WC.

Comment: @bobthechemist I don't know about about .NET, but I thought that the platform independent Mono/.NET executables also have an .exe extension.  The Mac version of .NET/Link also comes with an `InstallNET.exe`.  Perhaps this is not a Windows executable after all.

Comment: @bobthechemist Well, it turns out copying it does work :)  Note to the OP: I guess first thing to do is to just try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I tried this and it seems to work.

1. I copied `NETLink` from a Mac to `/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/SystemFiles/Link`.
2. I installed the full mono package: `sudo apt-get install mono-complete`
3. Started `wolfram`, loaded `` <<NETLink` ``, then evaluated `InstallNET[]`.  It seems to work.

I don't know much about .NET though so I can't test in detail.

Comment: Yup, got this far.  I wasn't able to get any of the examples to work properly, however.

Comment: @bobthechemist I'm not sure which examples are Windows specific ... many of them are GUI related.  So I only tried ``LoadNETType["System.GC"]; GC`Collect[];``, which seemed like something that should work across platforms.  It worked fine.   I think if something doesn't work, that's likely because the RPi version of Mono doesn't have it and not because of any limitations of .NET/Link.  But I might be wrong, I don't use .NET.

Comment: Good point, I tried the circumference one which didn't seem to work, but I also have insufficient knowledge of .NET to debug further.